# font-awesome with xpages does not take effect even after loading

Tags: xpages, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome in xpages.I have a theme named securePolling in which I am giving links to the resources
code inside securePolling is

```
<theme extends="webstandard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/ schema/stylekit.xsd" >

<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('true')}">
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>font-awesome-fontFamily.css</href>
</resource>
<resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('true')}">
     <content-type>text/css</content-type>
     <href>font-awesome-4.2.0/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css</href>
</resource>
```

so font-awesome folder is located in WebContent folder.
below is the code for xsp.properties

```
xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=false
xsp.application.timeout=30
xsp.compress.mode=gzip
xsp.error.page=error.xsp
xsp.html.page.encoding=utf-8
xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
xsp.persistence.maxviews=16
xsp.persistence.mode=basic
xsp.resources.aggregate=false
xsp.session.timeout=30
xsp.theme=securePolling.theme
xsp.upload.maximumsize=10000
```

after all this operation I can check in the browsers debug tool it is showing that font-awesome.css is loaded but the fonts does not takes effect for ant icon,
here is the image which will make more clear.[image: marked in red are font-awesome fonts]

After some research also tried changing font-awesome.css code to

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: "FontAwesome";
 src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
 src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
 src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
 src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
 src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }
```

any help would be really appreciated.

when aggregation changes to "false",it is working perfectly fine,but when it is "true" it does not takes effect.here is the image result and the console after changing to "true".[image: result and console after aggregation "true"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason behind the above issue was the path which I was given in ".css" files to the font files,which are located in font directory.

Now from the beginning we can see,the ".theme" file code in which resource path is "font-awesome-4.2.0/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

```
 <resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getProperty('xsp.resources.aggregate').equals('true')}">
 <content-type>text/css</content-type>
 <href>font-awesome-4.2.0/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css</href>
```

according to the path there are 2 folders and then font folder.So i have deleted one folder and made the path like this "font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css".

Now when I put aggregation On,the path to font folder looks like this.This worked for me.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url('font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
src: url('font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
src: url('font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
src: url('font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

When I put aggregation Off the code looks like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url('../../font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
src: url('../../font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
src: url('../../font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
src: url('../../font-awesome-4.2.0/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

for reference, the folder structure now is.

[image: font-awesome folder structure for reference]

This solution resolved my problem completely.

Comment: Thanx to Brian Gleeson, the answer and the comments both helped me to  resolve and get it done.Basically I was not getting the font file properly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that css should look like the following. But note, the relative urls here will only work with **aggregation turned off**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, are they definitely in a folder called "font"? Usually they are in a folder called "fonts" in the Font Awesome download.

With **aggregation turned on**, you'd need different relative urls:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url('../../../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
    src: url('../../../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('../../../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: url('../../../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

So you might want to create two versions of the font awesome css file, one loaded when aggregation is off, the other loaded when aggregation is on. Or have one version that uses absolute urls instead of relative ones.

Also beware that font awesome comes with a ".css" file and a minimised version ".min.css", so be sure to change both versions as needed.

Comment: sorry I have deleted the comment because when i am trying with aggregation On it come to same problem.

Comment: Is there an error in the console of the browser dev tools?

Comment: when i put aggregation Off it works very fine.but when its changed to true is behaves again the same as in above image

Comment: Did you create 2 versions of the CSS file as I suggested, or switch to using absolute URLs?

Comment: yes I have created font-awsome.min.css for aggregation On and font-awesome.css for aggregation Off.

Comment: Try changing the compression mode to none to see of that is causing issues. Is the font file successfully found and loaded in the network tab with aggregation on?

Comment: I have tried the by aggregation true and deleted the font folder but still have the same thing in image,it means the it is not getting the font files to take effect on aggregation true,as i have tried your suggestion given in answer to set the path accordingly when aggregation On,but no change.still facing the same issue.